# using ngram in clustering protein data (ngram.NGram.compare equivalent in R)

Tags: python, r, sequence, n-gram, protein-database

There is some sequence data to be compared. The expected output is the distance matrix which shows how similar each sequence is to the others. Previously, I used `ngram.NGram.compare` in Python and now I want to switch to R. I found `ngram` and `biogram` package but I was unable to find the exact function which generate the expected output.

Assume this is the data

```
a <- c("ham","bam","comb")
```

The output should be like this (distance between each item):

```
#      ham    bam   comb
#ham    0     0.5   0.83
#bam   0.5     0     0.6
#comb  0.83   0.6     0
```

It is the equivalent Python code for the output:

```
a = ["ham","bam","comb"]
import ngram
[(1 - ngram.NGram.compare(a[i],a[j],N=1))  
                          for i in range(len(a)) 
                          for j in range((i+1),len(a)) ]
```

Comment: Are the sequences of the same length?

Comment: @missuse The sequence that I have are from the same length. However, the above example is not. It is better to support same or different length. I don't think than 1-gram is length sensitive.

Comment: Could you explain in detail how the comparison is done using 1-gram?

Comment: @missuse I made it clear here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252396/ngram-representation-and-distance-matrix-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `stringdistmatrix` from the `stringdist` package. Check the `stringdist-metrics` documentation which metrics are available.

```
a <- c("ham","bam","comb")
stringdist::stringdistmatrix(a, a, method = "jaccard")

          [,1] [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.0000000  0.5 0.8333333
[2,] 0.5000000  0.0 0.6000000
[3,] 0.8333333  0.6 0.0000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Perhaps the output is not good. I know Jaccard method. I want to use ngram to compare two sequences. May the output be different from what I wrote above.

Comment: In that case you will have to give a better example of what you exactly want to compare and how it should look like.

Comment: I made it clear here. Now the question is different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252396/ngram-representation-and-distance-matrix-in-r